# How to call a javascript function defined externally using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `react.js` to render a `<script>` on an html page. Within this script, there is a javascript function that I need to call from within my react class.

This is what I have...

```
class Example extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() { 

        //render a script 
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http//random_source.js";

    render(){

         //call method from the script rendered
         window.someMethod();
         return(
             <div>{this.componentWillMount}</div>

              );
         }
     }
```

So `componentWillMount()` is rendering my script on the html page, and within the `render()` I'm calling `window.someMethod()` where `someMethod` is located inside the rendered script.

Is this possible using react? If not is there any work around?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking if this works. Why not try it?

Comment: @CalebAnthony I did try it look at my code ^^

Comment: @Bolboa It is possible like this - https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/51817/, however, why do you need load script inside react compoent? Do you use webpack? Maybe better add this script to general bundle?

Comment: @AlexanderT. I do not have access to the webpack which is why I wanted it done this way, but your answer solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts are asynchronous, so you need to wait for the script to be loaded and parsed. When this completes, the `onload` callback/event will be triggered

```
class Example extends React.Component {

    getInitialState(){
        return {loaded:false} //initially not loaded
    }

    componentWillMount() { 

        //render a script 
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http//random_source.js";

        //when the script loads, we're ready to go, so change state
        script.onload = (function(){ 
             this.setState({loaded: true}) 
        }).bind(this);

        //append the script to the DOM
        //you should take care not to include it twice
        // and if include to setState to loaded just as script.onload does
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    render(){
         if(!this.state.loaded){
             return (<div>Loading...</div>);
         }

         //call method from the script rendered
         window.someMethod();
         return(
             <div>{this.componentWillMount}</div>

              );
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is indeed possible using reactJS. I have implement few scroll events using this. The only condition is that your javascript should load before your reactjs component else undefined error would be thrown.

But if this is required only for this particular component you can implement it the component class only.

Comment: So in my example above, is the javascript being loaded before or after the method is called?

Comment: Why is this being implemented this way? I mean creating js element from reactjs? Why not put the js file in html and compile your reactjs files with webpack and put bundled file below it in your html code?